# What creatures give bonuses to Medicine rolls/checks?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, druid, wild-shape, animals

I am currently using a Druid in a campaign. I want to know what creatures, if any, there are that I can Polymorph or Wild Shape (5e Druid ability allowing druids to transform temporarily into Beasts) into that either give bonuses to Wisdom (Medicine) rolls/checks (like Medicine +3 for example) or that have advantage on Wisdom/ Wisdom (Medicine) rolls/check.

My character is a 6th level druid (Circle of the Land). I will soon have the *Polymorph* spell, but do not have *True Polymorph* or *Shapechange*

I will need to succeed on a DC 20 Wisdom (Medicine) check or one of my teammates will take quite a lot of Psychic damage when I attempt to remove the Control Gem of a Green Slaad. I want the best chance of rolling high enough.

My cantrips are: Druidcraft, Mending, Guidance, and Produce Flame (4 because of Circle of the Land).

Comment: Also, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## You're fresh out of Medical beasts

Both Wild Shape and *polymorph* are limited to Beast forms, which aren't typically assosciated with medical works.

In fact, you can search for creatures on D&D Beyond and [filter for creatures which are proficient with Medicine](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-search=&filter-skill-proficiency=13&filter-type=0). That list is humanoid heavy, including only three non-humanoids; [sirens](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/siren), [yakfolk priests](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/yakfolk-priest), and [autumn eladrin](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/autumn-eladrin) none of which are beasts. I don't know of any creatures with non-proficiency bonuses to medicine, and would certainly not expect any Beasts to have it.

Your best bets are going to be use [*enchance ability*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enhance-ability) to give yourself advantage on Wisdom checks. (Note that it does not work with your own *guidance* because they both require concentration.) Otherwise getting a Bard to inpire you, and any other skill increasing methods work (see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144371/what-is-the-highest-total-result-one-can-get-for-a-skill-check) for some ideas).

Comment: Thanks so much  Thanks to you DnD Beyond is now my favorite website 